# Java - Remove Specified Token of strings from the array of tokens

Tags: java, arrays

I'm finishing my homework, but I have a big problem with deleting duplicate token from the array of tokens and than shift towards left. I tried util remover, but it doesn't work, I don't know why.

Here is my part of code:

```
for ( int z = 0 ; z < liczbaTokenow-1 ; z++)
   {    
       for (int k = z+1 ; k<liczbaTokenow-1 ; k++)
       {       
           if (placek[z].compareTo(placek[k]) == 0)
           {
               System.out.println("I found a duplicated "+placek[k]);
               System.out.println("Should I remove it? Type:yes/no");
               Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
               odpowiedz=input1.nextLine();
               if ((odpowiedz=="yes") && (odpowiedz=="Yes") && (odpowiedz=="YES"))
               {
                  tokens[k]=null; HERE TOKEN "k" SHOULD BE DELETED FROM ARRAY OF TOKENS
               }
           }
       }
```

Can I count on your help? Thx in advance :)

Comment: While it might a legitimate question, the code example is highly confusing:
1) What is `liczbaTokenow`?
2) Why are we comparing `placek[<index>]`, but setting null to `tokens[]`?
3) Why is user input stored in variable name `odpowiedz`? If your actual output was in Polish, I would at least understand. But given that the question is asked in English, using this type of variable would confuse your fellow developers.

Without seeing the relationship between these variables above, I find it hard to confidently move forward with any other answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will never be true. Change this.

```
if ((odpowiedz=="yes") && (odpowiedz=="Yes") && (odpowiedz=="YES"))
```

To

```
if ("YES".equalsIgnoreCase(odpowiedz))
```

And by the way, a better way to remove duplicates from would be to use a [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) and add your values to set. This will be done in O(n) instead of O(n^2).

Comment: Probably it's not a good idea, my professor will check the internet if I didn't copy it :D and I wrote it by my own, so I don't want to fail the project in so stupid case ^^ maybe any e-mail or facebook method will be better?

Comment: I think array = ArrayUtils.removeElement(array, element) it will be good, but I use the newwest Netbeans and I can't import proper library....